# DNN - Is model binding possible?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, model-binding

I've always worked with asp.net mvc 4 and used model binding to display data to my view but also validating data in my model.

I do know that's possible to use model binding in later versions of asp.net but i have no idea if it's also possible in dotnetnuke.

So is it possible to use mel binding and could you maybe share some code if it's possible, i started with dotnetnuke yesterday and everything is still pretty new for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ASP.NET WebForms module binding without any issue as long as you are on .NET 4.5 and later on the server.

This involves using the ItemType property on the WebForms controls etc.  Any tutorial guided to ASP.NET WebForms model binding will work.